# getSercerSideProps not wroking Nextjs 13

Tags: reactjs, next.js, getserversideprops

I want to get content from Contentful using getServerSideProps in Next.js 13. However, when I try to console.log the value, it shows undefined. If I fetch the data inside the SalesTaxArticle component, it works fine, but I'm concerned about the impact on SEO, which is my main goal.

I have done this before in Nextjs 12, but I'm not sure why it doesn't work in Next js 13. What can I use that is good for SEO?

[code image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vq55n.png)

[code image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/13KUg.png)